# How to use ifconfig to show active interface(s) only and display interface name, MAC address & IP address only

Tags: ip, ip-address, mac-address, ifconfig

How can I use ifconfig to show active interface(s) only and display interface name, MAC address & IP address only. In my scenario, I could have more than one interface.

For example:

eth0   HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:11   inet addr: 192.168.0.1

Comment: By "active", do you mean "an interface that has an IP address assigned to it?" It's unclear to me whether you would consider `lo` "active".

Answer (score 1):

I think some manipulation for the output of the *ifconfig* command using *grep*, *cut* will do it.

for example the following line will extract the interfaces with flags UP, RUNNING and BROADCAST , to avoid the loopback and other stuff.. and the interface names are stored in myInterfaces

```
myInterfaces=`ifconfig | grep -E "UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING" | cut -d : -f 1`
```

you can then apply a loop over myInterfaces to run the *ifconfig*  separately for each item, and use grep to filter the output to give you just what you need

```
echo "${myInterfaces}" | while read line || [[ -n $line ]]
 do
  echo $line $(ifconfig $line | grep -E -o "ether.{0,18}") $(ifconfig $line | grep -E -o "inet .{0,15}"); echo ""
done
```

for me the output is as follows

```
enp0s20u1 ether 66:ad:53:93:91:bb inet 192.168.0.133

wlp3s0 ether 80:00:0b:d4:4d:f6 inet 192.168.0.138
```